# Send a JS variable to a specific Symfony route

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, symfony

I have a Symfony 3 project with Angular JS in front.
The project is about taking an URL with specific XML content, send it to SF3, do some manipulation, and send the final result to Angular JS.

I just want to catch my url variable in my Symfony Controller.

app.js

```js
var app = angular.module("test", []);


app.controller("testCtrl", ['$scope', '$http', '$window', function($scope, $http, $window) {


    $scope.getMyXML = function() {


        $http.get($scope.urlSubmitted)
            .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {


                $http({
                    method: 'POST',
                    url: Routing.generate('f_api'), //FOSJsRoutingBundle
                    headers: {},
                    params: {},
                    data: {urlToParse:$scope.urlSubmitted}
                }).then(function successCallback(response) {
                    console.log('Sended to SF3');
                }, function errorCallback(response) {
                    console.log('NOT sended to sf2');
                });


            })
            .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                alert('!! XML GET ERROR !!');
            })
    }

}]);
```

Symfony controller action

class MyController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {

```
    $serializer = $this->get('jms_serializer');
    $data = $request->request->get('urlToParse');
    //var_dump($data);
    //die;





    return $this->render('MyBundle:My:index.html.twig');
}

public function apiAction(Request $request)
{

    $data = $request->request->get('urlToParse');
    var_dump($data);
    die;

    return new JsonResponse();
}
```

}

And last, my routing.yml

```
    f_home:
    path:     /
    defaults: { _controller: MyBundle:My:index }

f_api:
    path:     /api/
    defaults: { _controller: MyBundle:My:api }
    options:
            expose: true
```

The apiAction is never lanched, despite of the angular http post on it...

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
data: {'urlToParse':$scope.urlSubmitted}
```

then:

```
$data = $request->request->get('urlToParse');
```

Comment: i have an indexAction (with my submit form), and an apiAction (i want to catch the url here. I have put your code, when i put a var_dump(data); die; in my apiAction, nothing appear when i submit my form...

Comment: did you try to pass your parameter with the url. ex: Routing.generate('my_route_to_expose', { id: 10 });

Comment: can you edit your post and add the annotations of your apiAction.

Comment: You can check now - )

Comment: aren't you calling your route with the wrong name. shouldn't be Routing.generate('f_api')

Comment: Riadh ? Are you here ?